# is there an ZSH equivalent to bash option "shopt -s expand_aliases"?

Tags: zsh, alias

I want to use aliases inside zsh scripts but it doesn't works. why?
(macbook Air M1 2020 Shell zsh)

Comment: _it doesn't work_ is a poor description of a problem. Aliases works inside zsh scripts. Please show a simple script which demonstrates the problem. Make sure that your script also contains a `echo $ZSH_VERSION`  command, so that we can see which zsh is executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

The option you are looking for is `ALIASES`, set with the `setopt` command.

```
setopt ALIASES
```

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning, that alias expansion by default is turned on, so a more likely use case is turning them off. The only case I could imagine a `setopt ALIASES` to be useful, is, if someone decides to turn alias expansion off inside his .zshenv, and then need it to be turned on again for certain scripts.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot `zsh` differs from `bash` in this.

Comment: It's possible the OP has an entirely different problem, too; I answered the question in the title, which may be an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found this
<< When you run script.sh it is executed in a subshell and your aliases won't propagate up to the calling shell (or current session as you refer to it). You need to source script.sh itself: source script.sh. That will cause the commands to be run in your current shell and the aliases will become visible.>>
[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386449/run-bash-script-doesnt-work-alias-command-in-zsh]
It seems also true with ZSH shell